# Response is 404 when term matcher added on path of api on using pact-stub-server

Tags: pact

```
  describe('Getting asset for player', () => {
   before(() => {
      return provider.addInteraction({
        given: 'GET call',
        uponReceiving: 'Get asset for player',
         withRequest: {
            method: 'GET',
            path: term({
            matcher: '/api/assets/[0-9]+',
            generate: '/api/assets/10006'
                }),
            },
            willRespondWith: {
                status: 200,
                headers: { 'Content-Type': 'application/json' },
                body: assetByPlayer
            }
        });
    });

    it('Get the asset by player', () => {
        return request.get(`http://localhost:${PORT}/api/assets/10006`)
        .set({ 'Accept': 'application/json' }).then((response) => {
            return expect(Promise.resolve(response.statusCode)).to.eventually.equals(200);
        }).catch(err => {
            console.log("Error in asset with player listing", err);

        });
    });
});
```

I get the json file as :  https://pastebin.com/TqRbTmNS

When i use the json file in other code base by pact stub server , it 
    gets the request from UI as 
    ===> Received Request ( method: GET, path: /api/assets/10006, query: 
    None, headers: Some({"actasuserid": "5", "content-type": "application/vnd.nativ.mio.v1+json", "host": "masteraccount.local.nativ.tv:30044", "accept": "application/json", "authorization": "Basic bWFzdGVydXNlcjptYXN0ZXJ1c2Vy", "connection": "close", "content-length": "2"}), body: Present(2 bytes) )

but does not sends any response

But if i just remove the matching rules part 
      "matchingRules": {
       "$.path": {
       "match": "regex",
       "regex": "\/api\/assets\/[0-9]+"
          }
       }
 it starts to work again

===> Received Request ( method: GET, path: /api/assets/10006, query: None, headers: Some({"authorization": "Basic bWFzdGVydXNlcjptYXN0ZXJ1c2Vy", "accept": "application/json", "content-length": "2", "connection": "close", "host": "masteraccount.local.nativ.tv:30044", "content-type": "application/vnd.nativ.mio.v1+json", "actasuserid": "5"}), body: Present(2 bytes) )

<=== Sending Response ( status: 200, headers: Some({"Content-Type": "application/json"}), body: Present(4500 bytes) )

and I can see the data to be present

Could you let me what is wrong here ?

Comment: Please share the output of any relevant logs. Also, you are showing code from your consumer test, but referring to the stubs server. Please share the contract file if you are running outside of the JS DSL

Comment: I have edited the post .Hope it will be clear now :)

Comment: It might be an issue with pact stub server vs the stub tool from the standalone package. Have you tried both? If one works and not the other, you should raise an issue in the repo

Comment: It does not work with pact stub server .I have already raised issue under pact-stub-server

Comment: Have you tried with https://github.com/pact-foundation/pact-ruby-standalone/releases and does that work?

Comment: yes it works fine that way.But for the above scenario , I want to use pact stub server

Comment: OK then its probably a bug - raise an issue there and we'll get it fixed.

Comment: i have raised this one https://github.com/uglyog/pact-stub-server/issues/26 .But no one has picked it up , could you please chase them up :)